# VBA Loop with more results

Tags: excel, vba

I have to compare 2 files xlsx. Both look the same. File 1 will be updated each day.

Now the script should compare each ID (individual numbers) in column 5 if it's in file 2, column 5 too. If yes, the text from File 1 column 4 (same row) whould be updated in file 2. If ID number is not in file 2 yet, than the complete row should be copied to the first free row in the end of file 2.

This is what i already have:

```
On Error Resume Next
   Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)
   Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
   wkb1.Activate
   Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(1)
   Set wks1 = wkb1.Worksheets(1)
   anz = wks.Cells(65536, 5).End(xlUp).Row
   anz1 = wks1.Cells(65536, 5).End(xlUp).Row
   For Z = 2 To anz1
    suchwert = wks1.Cells(Z, 5)
    With wks.Range("E2:E" & anz)
    Set c = .Find(suchwert, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        For s = 4 To 5
            wks.Cells(c.Row, s) = wks1.Cells(Z, s)
            Next
        Else
        For s = 1 To 9
            wks.Cells(anz + 1, s) = wks1.Cells(Z, s)
            Next
    End If
    End With
   Next Z
```

It's working fine for 1 result. But there are over 700 IDs on file 1.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Kind regards,
Chris

Comment: I think it work for all but you just replace cells value each time

Comment: If i start the code again and again, everything is working fine. But i have no idea where to set up the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
On Error Resume Next
   Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=my_FileName)
   Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
   wkb1.Activate
   Set wks = wkb.Worksheets(1)
   Set wks1 = wkb1.Worksheets(1)
   anz = wks.Cells(65536, 5).End(xlUp).Row
   anz1 = wks1.Cells(65536, 5).End(xlUp).Row
   Cpt = anz 

      For Z = 2 To anz1
       suchwert = wks1.Cells(Z, 5)
       With wks.Range("E2:E" & anz)
       Set c = .Find(suchwert, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
       If Not c Is Nothing Then

           For s = 4 To 5
               wks.Cells(c.Row, s) = wks1.Cells(Z, s)
               Next
           Else
           For s = 1 To 9
               Cpt = Cpt +1
               wks.Cells(Cpt, s) = wks1.Cells(Z, s)
               Next
       End If
       End With
      Next Z
```

Comment: @ChrisPE What does it did

Comment: The same result. I get one single updated line in File 2.

Comment: @ChrisPE File 2 is wks ?

Comment: Yes. wkb / wks is File 2

Comment: All entries are copied now. :) Maybe a small thing but all entries are pasted in a new row. Is there a way for: 4 To 5 should not insert in a new line. If entry is already in list, column 4 should be updated in the same line only. For 1 To 9 it's working fine so far. Only the new line is sliding down from left to right. So it looks like a down stairs. Can we fix this in a quick way?

Comment: For 4 To 5 it works fine with "wks.Cells(c.Row, s) = wks1.Cells(Z, s)".  Only 1 To 9 have the given stairs issue.

Comment: G'morning Dorian. I already tried this code. But for 1 To 9 each entry is insert in a new row (+1 from left to right).

Comment: i solve this issue by copy each entry single one. Like wks.Cells(Cpt, 1) = wks1.Cells(Z, 1), wks.Cells(Cpt, 2) = wks1.Cells(Z, 2)

Comment: @ChrisPE Glad That I could help you